# JSF 2.0 Facelets nested templates inheritance

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, facelets

Is it posible to define templates that inherit from other templates in facelets?

Something like this

```
/GlobalTemplate.xhtml

/users/UsersTemplate.xhtml template="/GlobalTemplate.xhtml"

/users/viewUser.xhtml template="/users/UsersTemplate.xhtml"
```

Then viewUsers.xhtml will be called by browser

Comment: That you're asking this trivial question gives me the impression that you're having problems with it. Is this true? In the future please elaborate about the problems instead of asking a rhetorical or a yes-no question.

Comment: Haha BalusC, I wasn't having problems with it. I was thinking of doing that. That is how templating is done in Stripes and I have done a lot of that in stripes so googled to see any examples and was surprised not to find any trace so it was either its so easy no one has bothered to write about it or not possible hence the silence so decided to ask.

Comment: I'd expect that you would experiment with it yourself first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's definitely possible.

Comment: Anyway, thanks for all the help so far. Remember u from the sun forums. Do u still hang around there?

Comment: Not anymore, those forums suck. Too many poor questions which you cannot improve, buggy forumsoftware, ugly UI and bad UX. Stackoverflow has solved this all.