# JSF 2.0 Facelets template inheritance

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

This is an extended repost of [JSF 2.0 Facelets nested templates inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323937/jsf-2-0-facelets-nested-templates-inheritance), which was loosely asked and formally answered.

Here is my easy_to_earn question:

**template_base.xhml**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
            xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
            xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<h:head><!-- header stuff --></h:head>
<h:body>
    <!-- Lot of html here -->
    <div id="main">
        <ui:insert name="main_content"/>
    </div>
    <!-- Lot of html here -->
</h:body>
</html>
```

Next, I want another template, **form_wrapped.xhtml**, which would *extend* **base_template.xhml** but with `main_content` wrapped by `<h:form>`:

```
<div id="main">
    <h:form>
        <!-- "main_content" goes here -->
    </h:form>
</div>
```

And the page itself:

```
<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/templates/form_wrapped.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="main_content">
            <!-- this html is wrapped by form -->
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make your `form_wrapped` template like this:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    template="/WEB-INF/templates/main_wrapped.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="main_content">
            <div id="main">
                <h:form>
                    <ui:insert name="form_content" />
                </h:form>
            </div>
    </ui:define>

</ui:composition>
```

Comment: Thanks, any chances that I could use the same "main_content" reference instead of introducing new "form_content"?

Comment: @Osw Yes, I believe you can do that by replacing `<ui:insert name="form_content" />` with `<ui:insert name="main_content" />` in the form_wrapped.xhtml template