# html <form> tag referencing a "super" form tag - Possible?

Tags: java, html, jsp

I know HTML is not a programming language and so applying Object Oriented principles is not possible, but, I have an annoying issue which would be simply solved if you could have a form tag inheriting from a parent form tag.

I want to split my JSP page up into logical form includes for various reasons, but mainly to aid the compartmentalisation of client side data input and associated server side handling in order to promote re-use of code.  However, there is one common, page scope value which I require to be submitted along with each, individual form submit.

I could duplicate this one input within each form but it seems crazy to have the same value duplicated several times on a page.  A javascript "onsubmit" function could also be the answer but that is useless when javascript is turned off.  I could also have a session scope variable in my java storing the value but I'd rather avoid that.

Any ideas other than sucking up the code duplication on the jsp?

Comment: What exactly is the data that you want to append to each form? Why you don't want to keep this data in session?

Comment: Do you dislike duplicating just the value or the whole input?

Comment: It's a page name string that is used for navigation.  Don't want to keep on session because of paranoia that it could become out of sync with the actual page being displayed therefore dumping the user on the wrong page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have individual forms on the page, then yes, you'll have to duplicate the common piece of data in all of those forms; there's no way to "inherit" it without using JavaScript on the client.

If it's hidden information (and it sounds like it is), you can include in each form's `action` attribute, and so your JSP code can make the duplication fairly innocuous:

```
<%
    // (Be sure to URL-encode the value if necessary, not shown here)
    String formAction = response.encodeURL("action.jsp?hiddenData=" + hiddenValue);
%>
...
<form action="<%=formAction%>">
...
</form>
...
<form action="<%=formAction%>">
...
</form>
...
```

Alternately you can include a `hidden` field in each form, again by doing it once in the JSP code and then dumping it out on each form.

Answer (score 0):

If you need "inheritance" in HTML JSP is not a good technology for that.

You should take a look at JSF where you will be able to inherit templates. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5646624/jsf-2-0-facelets-template-inheritance) for example.